# Adding methods to Class doesnot work in python3.7.0 same works with python 2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Below is my code and it works with python 2 and not with python 3,
minor changes have been added to make syntax compaitable with python3.
Please help with this.
ANd i get the error as

> TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

```
import collections
from types import MethodType

_ApiMethod = collections.namedtuple('_ApiMethod', ['name', 'path', 'http_method', 'query_params'])

API = [
    _ApiMethod('print_hello', 'api/hello', "GET", ['limit']),

]

class HelloClient(object):

    def __repr__(self):
        return "HelloClient(%s)" % ', '.join('%s=%s' % (a, repr(getattr(self, a))) for a in ['url', 'headers'])

    def get(self, path,query_params=None, headers=None, **kwargs):

        return "I am Hello Get Method"


def _add_methods():

    def _build_method(path, http_method, expected_query_params):

        if http_method == "GET":

            def _method(self, **kwargs):
                query_params = kwargs.setdefault('query_params', {})
                query_params.update({qp: kwargs[qp] for qp in expected_query_params if qp in kwargs})
                return self.get(path=path, **kwargs)

        return _method

    for api_method in API:        
        setattr(HelloClient, api_method.name, MethodType(_build_method(api_method.path, api_method.http_method, api_method.query_params or []), HelloClient))

_add_methods()
```

and i would call this method as

```
client = HelloClient()
response = client.print_hello()
```

Comment: You are adding the method to the class object. I could not find a way to add an instance method to the class, so I used metaclasses, as you can see from https://gist.github.com/fcracker79/bec718d0214db7c1b7bb67b31e1c605a

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue here is that you are mixing the old `unbound methods` from python 2 which were dropped in python 3.
Since python 3 classes no longer expose their function as `unbound methods`, running the following snippet:

```
class A:
  def f(self):
    pass

type(A.f)
```

Gives `function` in python 3 and `<type 'instancemethod'>` in python2. With this simplification in python 3 classes no longer have the correct mechanism to deal with `MethodType` as you'd expect.

The solution would be to just add a simple function (`_build_method` result) to the class.

---

The solution in this specific case would be changing:

```
setattr(HelloClient, api_method.name, MethodType(_build_method(api_method.path, api_method.http_method, api_method.query_params or []), HelloClient)
```

into:

```
setattr(HelloClient, api_method.name, _build_method(api_method.path, api_method.http_method, api_method.query_params or [])
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Bit confused with this, please help with an example and will be really helpful